# Summing over constant calendar week interval

Tags: r, sum

I am currently trying to aggregate a weekly data to monthly data, which looks like this:

```
UPS         WEEK    AP
1111112016  1       385.22
1111112016  2       221.63
1111112016  3       317.47
```

There are 132 different UPCs and weeks are indicated by 1 - 52. However, they vary across the different UPCs. In total I have 4,027 rows. 
I would like to aggregate over a 4 week interval until the next UPC category is reached. I have tried this code:

```
z = aggregate(x$AP, by=list(x$UPC, cut(x$WEEK, breaks=13, lables = T)), FUN = sum)
colnames(z) = c("UPC", "Month", "AP")
z = z[order(z$UPC),]
```

I get the following output:

```
    UPC        Month         AP
1   1111112016 (0.951,4.77]  1098.03
88  1111112016 (4.77,8.54]   1180.03
187 1111112016 (8.54,12.3]   491.18
303 1111112016 (12.3,16.1]   896.31
```

There are several problems here:
1) The month value is wrong. I would like to have a numerical value. (1 - 12)
2) The first two aggregates are correct, however after that the sums seem sometimes to be correct and sometimes not.

Here is a brief example of how my data looks like:

```
dput(head(x))
structure(list(UPC = c(1111112016, 1111112016, 1111112016, 1111112016, 
1111112016, 1111112016), WEEK = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), AP = c(385.22, 
221.63, 317.47, 173.71, 269.55, 311.48)), .Names = c("UPC", "WEEK", 
"AP"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work (where data is your dataframe):

```
require(data.table)                                                                                                                                                   "AP"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(data)
result <- data[, .(AP=sum(AP, na.rm = T)), by = .(UPC, MONTH = (floor(WEEK/ 4.34) + 1))]
result <- result[order(UPC)]
```

And the result will be:

```
        UPC   MONTH    AP
1: 1111112016     1 1098.03
2: 1111112016     2  581.03
```

Comment: It looks better. But there is a problem with the calculation part. For example the 1. month is 924.43, but it should be around 1098

Comment: It looks better, almost perfect. However, there seems a problem related to the nature of calendars. 52/4 = 13. It is not related to this questions, but do you know how to get it to 12?

Comment: If we see it it per year. 4Q each divided by 3m means 17.33 weeks. If we divide that by 3 months we get 5.77 weeks. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: I added a workaround that will assign the 52nd week to the 12th month. (I just divided by (52weeks  / 12months) ) Will that give you the result you want? The problem is that some months have 4 weeks and some 5, because it cannot assign a week to 2 months...

Comment: That is true. It is a tricky. Especially, if it comes to index calculations. It works thank you. It is an nice combination or R commands.